# Contact us form with image captcha

Tags: php

I am new in PHP. I want my captcha validator to display error message if captcha is not the same with image. But if it is the same, I want to process the form and send email. Currently, if captcha is correct, an echo just says success and form does not process. I got my contact us form here http://www.html-form-guide.com/files/contact-form/contact-form-attachment-2.zip. Please help

Comment: Please show your code and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Here is the code for contactform.php

Comment: Plz use the above link it is the same code

Answer (score 0):

In your contactform.php check the if condition for the submitting form.

Change

`if(isset($_POST['submitted']))`

To

`if(isset($_POST['submit']))`

Comment: I have done this but it still shows an echo of success when I submit the for, it does not send email. From the link above, the captcha is on the show-captcha.php

Comment: check your phpMailerObject,.  In the fgcontactform.php in the function SendFormSubmission(). As my guess the from address is set as nobody@localhost so kindly check this.

Comment: Yes I have found that and changed it to the user email, but my main problem is that is still does not submit the form, the captcha just verify and echoz success, but doesn't process form. That is on the show-captcha.php